# Matrix and its condition number

Tags: condition-number

This example is given in Higham [2002], and is provided without explanation. I am not sure how the condition number of the matrix is just 5. How can you directly calculate the condition number of a matrix with epsilon? I know that cond(A) = $\left\Vert |A^{-1}||A| \right\Vert_{\inf}$, but I'm not sure how that helps here.

I calculated $A^{-1} = \{(1, -1/\epsilon, 1),(0, 1/\epsilon, -1), (0, 0, 1)\}$

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/px0eP.png)

Comment: Please include in your question what you have tried. eg have you computed $A^{-1}$ (in terms of $\epsilon$)?

Comment: Did you compute $A^{-1}$?

Comment: I get $\operatorname{cond}_\infty T = \max(3,{2 \over |\epsilon|}) \max (2, 2 |\epsilon|)$, $\operatorname{cond}_\infty T^T = (1+|\epsilon|)\max(2,{2 \over |\epsilon|} )$.

Comment: @copper.hat What method did you use to calculate the condition number of T?

Comment: $\|T\|_\infty \|T^{-1}\|_\infty$.

Comment: So can we not reproduce cond(T) = 5?

Comment: I made some computational mistakes above, but, regardless of norm chosen, the condition number of $T$ (and $T^T$) varies as ${1 \over \epsilon}$ for small $\epsilon$. (This is because all norms are equivalent.)

Comment: Note that $\|A\|_\infty$ is just the $\max$ row sum (of the absolute values), so is easy to compute.

Comment: +1 Is $\left\Vert |T^{-1}||T| \right\Vert_{\inf}$ the same thing as $\left\Vert T \right\Vert_{\inf} \left\Vert T^{-1} \right\Vert_{\inf}$ ?

Comment: No, I presumed that was a typo., since we're talking about condition number. Usually, $\operatorname{cond} A = \|A\| \|A^{-1}\|$. However, I am frequently mistaken :-).

Comment: Do you have a more detailed description of Higham's paper, he seems to be a prolific lad, so a search turns up more than I am willing to troll through.

Comment: @copper.hat Higham [2002, pg144] _Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms_

Comment: The condition number that Higham uses in that section is the one you have in the question which is different than the condition number one typically uses in the context of matrices. If you compute $|T^{-1}| |T|$ and take the $ \infty$ induced norm, then the result is $5$, as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|T| = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & |\epsilon| & |\epsilon| \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $

$|T^{-1}| = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & {1 \over |\epsilon|} & 1 \\
0 & {1 \over |\epsilon|} & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

$|T||T^{-1}| = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

$\| |T||T^{-1}| \|_\infty = 5$.